# How to watch the variables(global and local variable) value embedding in c# Code?

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I'm using IronPython embedding in vs2012 with c# code. and I need to watch the Var's Value when the script is debugging? is the current Version IronPython support this ? if it suppord ,Is there any method which I can use ?or when the IronPython can support it ?

Could you please give me some help ? you can see my project there:[IronPython-Debugger](https://github.com/heyxEvget/IronPython-Debugger/tree/master/SoftWare)
I use this code:

```
engine.SetTrace(OnTraceback);

private void OnTraceback(TraceBackFrame frame, string result, object payload)
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case "call":
        TracebackCall();
        break;
        case "line":
        TracebackLine();
        break;
        case "return":
        TracebackReturn();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: never used ironPython, but isn't VS already have breakpoint for you?
point mouse over the variables will show their value too

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you should be able to set breakpoints in the sections of code that you wish to monitor the values in. While in debugging mode with the breakpoint(s) reached you should be able to hover the mouse over the variable to reveal its value. You can also right-click on the variable to add a watch for the variable which will show the values for the variables you set a watch for. I am not familiar with ironpython, but if you are using Visual Studio these features should be available to you. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi,Disk0rd
   thanks for your help, and I'm working on what you have post to me,so the big problem is how to get the Vars(global-and-local) Values when i  step (s) into the code, I have no idea to solve it.